# Удаление образа в Docker используя флаг -f

Tags: docker

Что делает этот флаг `-f` , при удалении всех образов в Docker?

В чём разница между таким удалением, без флага `-f` :

```
docker rmi $(docker images)
```

и таким, используя флаг `-f` :

```
docker rmi -f $(docker images)
```

Answer (score 1):

Если на один image установлен один или более тэгов, то докер не позволит удалить образ до удаления этих тэгов.

Флаг -f удаляет в том числе и тэги образов.

[Подробнее](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rmi/#examples)